# Show that the absolute convergence of $\sum_{j =1}^\infty a_{k_j}$ does not imply the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Show that the absolute convergence of $\sum_{j =1}^\infty a_{k_j}$ does not imply the absolute convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.

Let $a_k = (-1)^k \cdot \frac{1}{k}$ and $a_{k_j} = (1/4, -1/9, 1/16, -1/25, \dots)$ i.e. the terms with square denominators. Now $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{k_j}| = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}< \infty$$ which implies that $a_{k_j}$ converges absolutely. However $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ which is the harmonic series and doesn't converge.

Am I defining the subsequence $a_{k_j}$ in a valid way? I think I should be able to extract the terms with square denominators from $a_k$ and then since the absolute value of those terms will give me the series $\frac{1}{n^2}$ starting from $n=2$ I get convergence.

Comment: Not really because they don't require the absolute convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$... only the convergence... since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ does converges, it doesn't work. However, you can do a similar argument with $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$... (and taking $k_j$ being an increasing sequence of perfect square)

Comment: You do not control any term $k$ with $k\notin\{k_j\}_{j=1}^\infty.$ Such terms may tend to infinity, for example.

Comment: @Surb Sorry I had a typo on the problem statement. The absolute convergence was required.

Comment: my answer is still the same...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the argument. If $a_{k_j}$ is a subsequence of $a_k$ that has a absolute convergent sum and $a_k$ doesn't haven't I shown what was asked? @Surb

Comment: Take $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and $k_j$ being the perfect square, i.e. $k_j=j^2$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\infty $ however, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{k_j}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}<\infty $.